# What's up with the Adobe AIR HTML development socket reference?

Tags: html, sockets, reference, air

I'm trying to reconcile the various Adobe AIR HTML guides, and am totally lost. I want to do something with a socket.

Some general guides on the topic [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7caf.html) and [here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=4&postId=10567) refer to `Air.Socket();` But the supposedly [Adobe AIR HTML reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/net/Socket.html) looks like it's not even JavaScript and it references a namespace (`window.runtime.flash.net.Socket`) that never comes up anywhere else in Adobe AIR HTML documentation. I've done some work with Flex, and these docs here look like they're for Flex, not for JavaScript. How am I supposed to know where functionality I want to use is and what it's called if all the references are for Flex?

Is there any useful **reference** documentation that tells me just what is in the `Air.*` namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah figured it out. So I opened the accompying AIRAliases.js file that comes for HTML developers and it maps the namespaces in the references to the namespaces for AIR.